# C++ -- Incorrect signature for assignment operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

I'm struggling to basically understand how the assignment operator works, or perhaps I haven't defined the right one, or I've come upon some C++ gotcha; not sure.

I have a class like this:

```
class A
{
 public:

   A();
   A(const A &rhs);

   //some other ctors
   //and functions here

   A& operator=(A rhs);
   A  create_half();

   double* m_data;

};
```

Here is the body of create_half; it appears to be relevant to the situation

```
A A::create_half(){

  //construct a new A
  A mya;

  //do stuff to mya here,
  //and then return the new A
  return mya;

}
```

Here is the copy constructor, at least a shortened version of it.  This is the code that is skipped due to standard -- at least if this is what's truly going on.

```
A::A(const A& rhs):
 m_data(new double[1])
{
    *m_data = *(rhs.m_data);
    //or something similar, essentially
    //a deep copy
}
```

Then in the code I try to write something like this

```
A a_instance;

//do stuff to a_instance

//this doesn't call any = operator or 
//copy c-tor I try to define, why?
A b_instance = A.create_half(); 

//but this works fine
//the = operator I have def'd is called
A b_instance;
b_instance = A.create_half();
```

The line that doesn't work as I want it to seems to do a default copy (ie, b_instance.m_data is set to a_instance.m_data) even though neither my copy c-tor now my assignment operator contain this operation.

For the problematic line, I'm not able to step into the assignment operator; that's why I think I have the wrong signature, or something similar.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Sorry for misleading you guys -- no class B exists.

EDIT AGAIN: I've accepted an answer, and I've added some detail to the snippets above to try to elucidate what is really going on.

Since the instance of A created by create_half() isn't bound to a reference, the standard allows elision of the copy constructor, which, critically, allocates new memory for b_instance, and does the deep copy.

That seems pretty bold, to me!  I don't think I'll see an answer, since this edit is sometime after the initial posting, but what would be a better design pattern here?

Comment: Assignment meant you assign a value to something that already exists. `T t = x;` is an initialization, so it doesn't involve any assignments. Also, `A a_instance();` is actually declaring a function.

Comment: The assignment operator should take its argument as a const-reference: `A& operator=(const A& rhs);`

Comment: Show us the code for `class B`. That's where the operators and contructors should be called.

Comment: @Casey, On the contrary. Take it by value and use the copy-swap idiom.

Comment: @Casey `A& operator=(A rhs);` is a valid copy assignment operator.

Comment: @chris: What if a value-copy is prohibitively expensive?

Comment: @Casey I guess then you're generally screwed and have to find alternatives. But if a type is prohibitively expensive to copy then perhaps it shouldn't be copyable.

Comment: @Casey, You're copying over the same data anyway when you assign a new object to it. If that's too much of a problem to use copy-swap, it's too much of a problem to have copy assignment. Let's not forget it also enables moving into the parameter if you assign an rvalue to it, so copying doesn't always happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
A a_instance();
```

is a function declaration that has no parameters and has return type A.

This statement

```
B b_instance = A.create_half();
```

syntactically is invalid. At least it should be written as

```
B b_instance = A().create_half();
```

In this statement an object of type B is created from an object of type A. I can say nothing whether this statement is correct because you did not show the class B definition.

This statement is also invalid

```
b_instance = A.create_half();
```

There must be

```
b_instance = A().create_half();
```

There is used indeed an assignment operator (maybe even the copy assignment operator provided that class B has a conversion constructor or class A has a conversion function) but for class B. You did not show how you defined class B. So again I can say nothing what is wrong with this assignment operator.

As for the signature of the copy assignment operator of class A

```
A& operator=(A rhs);
```

then it is valid though it would be better if you declared it as

```
A& operator=( const A &rhs );
```

**EDIT:** As you changed your original post then I need to append my message relative to your question in the following code snippet

```
//this doesn't call any = operator or 
//copy c-tor I try to define, why?
A b_instance = A.create_half();
```

According to the C++ Standard

> 31 When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit
>   the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the constructor
>   selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the
>   object have side effects. In such cases, the implementation treats the
>   source and target of the omitted copy/move operation as simply two
>   different ways of referring to the same object, and the destruction of
>   that object occurs at the later of the times when the two objects
>   would have been destroyed without the optimization.

One of the "certin criteria" is

> — when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference
>   (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same
>   cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by
>   constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the
>   omitted copy/move

Comment: Thanks Vlad, and sorry for my typos...they wasted your time.

That standard snippet you posted is certainly strange.  I think that must be what's going on, because I'm pretty sure I have all the code there.

My best guess is that since I'm not modifying b_instance afterward (I'm just writing a test program for my class), the code meets the "certain criteria".

Comment: I'm going to add some information to the original question to highlight what I think is going on. Thanks!